# Custom Square Button

Tags: android, android-view

I am trying to make a custom button, and I have 2 questions:

1. How can I assign a xml layout file as the layout for my custom button?
2. How can I assure the custom button is square? (satisfy height = width or width = height depending on which is smaller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say Custom Button I assume you are trying to create a Button by extending View or Button. With this assumption..

1) you can use your custom button in your layout file by using its full class name

Ex:

```
Instead of <Button />  use <com.xxx.MyButton />
```

More info: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

2) And by overriding onMeasure() you can control the width and height of your Button. Refer above android doc for more info.